# async autosave from property setter in C# WPF

Tags: c#, properties, async-await, fire-and-forget

We have WPF application that automatically saves data off to the database as soon as a property is set.  The call to do the save is in an async method.

I don't need to await the call.  It's basically fire and forget, unless an exception occurs.

We we're handling this with events, invoking the event from the property setter.  In this way we could have async void event handlers, then be async/await all the way down through the save routine.  Exception handling is working well with this pattern.

```
private async void Save(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e){}
private event PropertyChangedEventHandler SaveEvent;

public MyClass()
{
    SaveEvent += Save;
}

public int Foo
{
    get => _foo;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _foo, value);
        SaveEvent?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs());
    }
}
```

Do we really need these events? What are the ramifications of just calling the async void method directly like this?  Specifically as it pertains to exception handling, will an exception ever be caught?

```
private async void Save(){}

public int Foo
{
    get => _foo;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _foo, value);
        Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the event or directly calling `Save()` it is functionally the same. The most likely reason why it isn't directly called is due to the best practice advice for `async void` methods and that is you should only use it for event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we really need these events? What are the ramifications of just calling the async void method directly like this? Specifically as it pertains to exception handling, will an exception ever be caught?

Calling it directly is functionally equivalent. Exception handling will behave the same way.

On a side note, I recommend using your "property changed" notification as input to a debouncing function that will only autosave after a short delay. And you'll need to think about how to communicate pending/successful/failed autosaves to the user.

Comment: We are doing a refactor where we need to call them directly instead of using events.  Is it better practice to make the void methods return Tasks and invoke them through a lambda?  like SaveInvoke(async () => await Save()) or something like that.

Comment: @grinder22: No; I wouldn't say that's better.